# working with a boolean list in python

Tags: python, list, boolean

I am working on a tournament program for class. The program is supposed to have the user input all of the team names, select 2 teams, and ask the user which team won, and the winner will move on. I want to do this all in one array by using boolean values. I want all of the values in the array to start off as `false`, and if they win that team name turns to `true`.

So far I have this

```
amount = int(raw_input('How many teams are playing in this tournament?   ')
teams = []
i = 0
while i < amount:
    teams.append(raw_input("please enter team name:   ")
    i = i + 1
```

Now, how can I make the whole list `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a dictionary instead of a list is a better approach, in my opinion. You just add each team name as a key to the dictionary and set its corresponding value to `False` or `True`, respectively:

```
amount = int(raw_input('How many teams are playing in this tournament?   ')
teams = {}
i = 0
while i < amount:
    team_name = raw_input("please enter team name: ")
    teams[team_name] = False
    i = i + 1
```

If you want to choose the team that has won a match, you just do a team name lookup in the dictionary and set its value to `True`. This way, you can keep the team names and the boolean values in one data structure instead of needing two data structures or always replacing team names with boolean values which would not make sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already know the number of teams (amount), You can do

```
team_status = [False]*amount
```

Here, the index of `teams` and `team_status` would be the same, so it would be a simple lookup everytime you want the status of a particular team.

OR

You could use a dictionary

```
amount = int(raw_input('How many teams are playing in this tournament?   ')
teams = {}
for i < range(amount):
    team_name = raw_input("please enter team name:   ")
    teams.update({team_name: False})
```

Comment: You sure? You'd still have to calculate amount or change your while exit condition

Comment: Why is that? Is'nt `amount` a user's input ?

Comment: is there a way to do this in the same array? like assign the elements in my original list to true or false?

Comment: A list of dictionaries may be ?

Comment: oh, I see, it looks like a dictionary is what i was looking for. Thanks for your help!